# Why do JToolbarbuttons work on Netbeans IDE but not in executable jar format

Tags: java, user-interface

The JToolbar buttons of my application don't respond at all when clicked in .jar format but respond perfectly on Netbeans IDE, I really don't understand why I'm having this problem, here is an image illustrating the JToolBarButtons that are not responding on the application:

[image: http://i59.tinypic.com/282kxgo.png]

Also, the part of the code that I think is having the problem is shown below:

```
public class MainMenu extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
 MyDesktopPane dp = new MyDesktopPane();
    String TITLE    = "The complete payroll system ";
    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    JPanel panel_Bottom = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel_Top = new JPanel();
    JButton btnOut = new JButton(new ImageIcon(getClass ().getResource("logout.png")));
             Image img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/16.jpg")).getImage();

public MainMenu() {
    super("PayRoll System");

    panel_Top.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel_Top.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10,150));
    JToolBar tool=createJToolBar();tool.setBackground(new Color(36,121,183));
    panel_Top.add(tool,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    getContentPane().add(panel_Top,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    getContentPane().add(dp,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    btnOut.setBounds(600,230,75,35);
    dp.add(btnOut);
 {    
    btnOut.addActionListener(this);

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){

 public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
 {
     UnloadWindow();

 }
 });

}
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    Login log= new Login();
    Object source = e.getSource();
        if(source == btnOut){
            log.setLogin();
            dispose();
        }

}
protected JToolBar createJToolBar()
{
    JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar("Toolbar");
    toolbar.add(CreateJToolbarButton("Employee-Entry", "employee.png", "Emp_Entry",
            JToolBarActionListener));
            toolbar.addSeparator();
    toolbar.add(CreateJToolbarButton("Employee Position Settings", "setting.png","Settings",
            JToolBarActionListener));
    toolbar.addSeparator();

    toolbar.add(CreateJToolbarButton("DTR", "admin.png","DTR",
            JToolBarActionListener)); 
            toolbar.addSeparator(); 



            toolbar.add(CreateJToolbarButton("User - Settings", "inf.png","User_Settings",
            JToolBarActionListener));
                toolbar.addSeparator();


            toolbar.add(CreateJToolbarButton("Cash_Advance", "cash.png","Cash_Advance",
            JToolBarActionListener));
        toolbar.addSeparator();

            toolbar.add(CreateJToolbarButton("Employee - Payoll", "rep.png","Reports_Payroll",
            JToolBarActionListener));
        toolbar.addSeparator();



    toolbar.add(CreateJToolbarButton("Notepad", "SimpleTextEdit.png", "Notepad",
            JToolBarActionListener));
        toolbar.addSeparator();         
    toolbar.add(CreateJToolbarButton("Calculator", "Calculator2.png", "Calculator",
            JToolBarActionListener));
        toolbar.addSeparator(); 


    return toolbar;

}

ActionListener JToolBarActionListener = new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        empSettings set= new empSettings();
        empEntry inf= new empEntry();
        UserSettings panel1 = new UserSettings();
        notepad note= new notepad();
        BasicCalc calc= new BasicCalc();
        empDeduction frameDeduct= new empDeduction();
            empCashAdvance cash= new empCashAdvance();
        empPayroll pay = new empPayroll();
        String source = e.getActionCommand();     

        if(source == "Emp_Entry")
        {
             inf.setEntry();              
        }
        if (source == "Settings")
        {
             set.setSettings();            
        }
        if (source == "Reports_Payroll")
        {
               pay.setPay();           
        }
        if (source == "DTR")
        {
           frameDeduct.setDeduct();
        }
        if (source == "Notepad")
        {
          note.setNote();
        }
        if (source == "Calculator")
        {
          calc.setCalc();
        }
        if (source == "User_Settings")
        {
            panel1.frameUser();

        }


        if(source == "Cash_Advance")
        {
             cash.setCash(); 
        }   
    }
};



protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g.create();

    Image img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/16.jpg")).getImage();

    graphics.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);


    graphics.dispose();
}    


protected void UnloadWindow()
{
try
    {
    int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,"Are you sure to exit?",TITLE,JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        {
            setVisible(false);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else {

        }
    }
catch(Exception e)
    {}
}

    public JButton CreateJToolbarButton(String srcToolTipText,String srcImageLocation,String srcActionCommand, ActionListener JToolBarActionListener)
{
    JButton bttnToolbar = new JButton(new ImageIcon(getClass ().getResource (srcImageLocation)));

    bttnToolbar.setActionCommand(srcActionCommand);
    bttnToolbar.setToolTipText(srcToolTipText);
    bttnToolbar.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    bttnToolbar.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    bttnToolbar.addActionListener(JToolBarActionListener);
    return bttnToolbar;
}
    public void setMain(){
        MainMenu p1= new MainMenu();
        p1.setSize(1228,700);
        p1.setLocation(70,15);
        p1.setVisible(true);
        p1.setResizable(false);
}
 public static void mainPane(){
         new MainMenu ();
     }
```

I would be grateful if anyone could help me with this, thanks.

Comment: Have you ensured that the resources are getting added to the jar by listing its contents? Are they in the expected resource location, if so?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Sorry, I'm quite new to packaging in jar, as a result I don't understand what you mean by the resources getting added by listing its contents, I thought Netbeans takes care of all that.

Comment: @damolaolawle Perhaps it does, but you'd mentioned a jar it creates. Use jar -tf <jarpath> to list the contents of the jar and see how things are laid out and look for the resources in the jar you're looking for. Sometimes IDEs maintain context in a way that can satisfy their own references but don't have the instructions or configuration necessary to write the contents to the distribution.  It's important to be able to understand your application and how it is exported into a jar and how to find the resources.

Comment: @damolaolawle    Also, I edited your question so the picture will actually be displayed in the question to save reviewers time and make your question more appealing to answer. Please accept the edits so others can see them.

Comment: Thanks again for the replies but how do I accept your edit?

Comment: @damolaolawle I think if you try to edit it, you'll see pending edits and should be able to accept. It can also be accepted by peers instead of you, and sometimes they do accept others edits.  If you can't see and accept my edit, just edit the same thing in yourself by using the icon in the edit window that shows mountains and the Sun - that lets you add an image from your computer or via URL to the content. Then, after if the URL is still in the text and hasn't been converted to image notation, leave the image notation and delete the superfluous URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by opening **regedit.exe**, then navigating to **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jarfile\shell\open\command** and changing the Javaw.exe path in the value: **"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %** to: **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %**.

The **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe"** is the Javaw.exe path that my IDE is using to execute the application without any issues, the JToolbar buttons now work perfectly when the application is launched outside Netbeans IDE.